# collapse parent and child java classes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I've inherited an abstract parent class with only a single child class, both in 
separate files.

They're big and ugly. And they're no-longer structured correctly. 
I'm going to refactor them to be much nicer - but as part of this I'd
first like to collapse them into a single class. I.e. to go from something like this:

```
public abstract class ParentClass implements SomeInterface {

   ParenClass(SomeOtherClass v) {
     aMember = v;
   }

   @NonNull final SomeOtherClass aMember;

   abstract void doSomething();

   // Several hundred lines of other functions and members.
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    ChildClass(AnotherClass v2) {
       super(v2.getSomething());
       this.childMember = v2.somethingElse();
    }

    @NonNull final SomeOtherClass aMember;

    @Override void doSomething() {
      //...
    }

    // Several hundred lines of other functions and members
}
```

To a merged version of both classes (Could actually be named like either
of the original classes though...)

```
public class MergedParentAndChild implements SomeInterface {

   JustOneClass(AnotherClass v2) {
      this.aMember = v2.getSomething();
      this.childMember = v2.somethingElse();
   }

   void doSomething() {
      //...
   }
   // Lots of other functions etc.
}
```

I've done this by hand using the "pull up" refactor on all members but it's time consuming as
it gets constructors wrong and has issues with final members and abstract functions etc.

Maybe eclipse probably has a quick way to do this directly in its lists of refactorings. I just can't seem to find it.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: what is it that you need refactoring? Sorry it is late I can't seem to think XD

Comment: I'm trying to replace an unnecessary two class hierachy with just one class. The separation into parent and child class is inappropriate (or no longer appropriate) and getting in the way of further refactoring. I can do it by hand, or using "pull up" refactor on each function/field, one-by-one, but there's unfortunately a great many members, and a great number of classes with a similar issue.

Comment: is my answer confusing? XD sorry if it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "pull up" refactor isn't as repetitive/painful as I'd initially thought. I'm going to borrow JClassic's example and modify it a little (to make it *worse*) and show what happens

Here's the original code.

```
public class Temp {

    public static interface I1 {
        public void interfaceFn1();
        public void interfaceFn2();
    }

    public static abstract class A implements I1 {
        int a;
        public void foo(){
            System.out.printf("%s In A a=%d\n", this, a);
        }

        @Override public void interfaceFn1() {
            System.out.println("In A.interfaceFn1");
        }
    }

    public static class AA extends A {
        int aa;

        @Override 
        public void foo(){
            super.foo();
            System.out.printf("%s In AA a=%d, aa=%d\n", this, a , aa);
        }

        @Override public void interfaceFn2() {
            System.out.println("In A.interfaceFn1");
        }
    }
}
```

If you then put the cursor on one of the functions in AA and select the "
"pull up" refactor. (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>) - you get the following dialog.

[image: Pull up dialog]

Then click select all on the right, and next.

You get warnings about duplicate functions, which will cause compile errors, in a dialog that looks like this. You can just ignore these, and fix them later.

[image]

Then going to finish you get code that looks like this:

```
public class Temp {

    public static interface I1 {
        public void interfaceFn1();
        public void interfaceFn2();
    }

    public static abstract class A implements I1 {
        int a;
        int aa;
        public void foo(){
            System.out.printf("%s In A a=%d\n", this, a);
        }

        @Override public void interfaceFn1() {
            System.out.println("In A.interfaceFn1");
        }

        @Override public void foo() {
            super.foo();
            System.out.printf("%s In AA a=%d, aa=%d\n", this, a , aa);
        }

        @Override public void interfaceFn2() {
            System.out.println("In A.interfaceFn1");
        }
    }

    public static class AA extends A {
    }
}
```

You can now remove the class `AA` and fix the errors in `A` (duplication of `foo()` being the main issue) . Resulting in code like this:

```
public class Temp {

    public static interface I1 {
        public void interfaceFn1();
        public void interfaceFn2();
    }

    public static abstract class A implements I1 {
        int a;
        int aa;
        private void fooBase(){
            System.out.printf("%s In A.fooBase a=%d\n", this, a);
        }

        @Override public void interfaceFn1() {
            System.out.println("In A.interfaceFn1");
        }

        public void foo() {
            fooBase();
            System.out.printf("%s In AA a=%d, aa=%d\n", this, a , aa);
        }

        @Override public void interfaceFn2() {
            System.out.println("In A.interfaceFn1");
        }
    }
}
```

The biggest remaining problem is to switch all creations/references of `AA` to `A`. But if you selected the `use destination type where possible` that will reduce the number of places you will need to fix.

I suspect there are still cases where constructors cause some issues, but this seems OK for most cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is really hard (if not impossible) to automate the combination of two hierarchy classes: consider the following: you have two classes

```
public static class A {
    int a;
    public void foo(){
        //do stuff
    }
}

public static class AA extends A {
    int aa;

    @Override 
    public void foo(){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

When you merge them, you run into the problem:

```
public static class AMerged{
    int a;
    int aa; //this is fine
    public void foo(){ //but use who's implementation?
        //do what?
    }
}
```

With this, you run into the problem of method names being the same name, same with variables being the same, who's implementation will I use? The child or parent? As you can see, there are lots of problems in merging two classes you will run into, so it is nearly impossible to automate.

Even with abstract classes there is no way to combine them other than to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this can be done by class inline.

First, you need to pull up subclass method to parent class;

Then, you can inline the subclass. (Intellij Idea, place cursor on subclass, refactor->inline. Intellij Idea will remove subclass, and replace subclass with parent class)